# No module named 'azure.eventhub'; 'azure' is not a package

Tags: python, azure, pycharm, azure-eventhub

I am trying to execute this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/examples/recv.py) using Python 3.7 with Pycharm and `azure-eventhub 1.2.0` package.

When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.eventhub'; 'azure' is not a package
```

This is the problematic line:

```
from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset
```

What could be happening?

This is my project interpreter

[image: project interpreter]

Using pip freeze:

[image: pip freeze]

Comment: notice your pycharm project interpreter

Comment: try running `pip freeze` from a PyCharm terminal and see if you have `azure.eventhub` and also run `python` then import. Probably some configuration issue.

Comment: @BhathiyaPerera yes, i'm having same issue running python and then import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I known, there is a case which will cause your issue.

The Python Interpreter searches the available packages, objects and methods in the paths of `sys.path` in order, you can print the value of the `sys.path` variable to see the order after `import sys`.

So if there is a Python script named `azure.py` prior to the real `azure` package, you will get the issue `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.eventhub'; 'azure' is not a package`.

Here is my steps to reproduce this issue.

1. I created a Python script named `azure.py` in the current path which only have one line code `print('pseudo azure package')`.
   [image]
2. Then, I opened my Python interpreter in the current path and type `from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset`, then to get the issue as below.
   [image]

It also will happen in Pycharm, even using `virtualenv`, please check whether exists a file called `azure.py` or `azure.pyc` in your current path or the paths in the order of `sys.path` list.